# Ui component checbox value is 0 with js element

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, checkbox

This is my component field

```
    <field name="is_campaign_plp" formElement="checkbox">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Cpy_Cms/js/form/element/plp-campaign</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">plp</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <dataType>boolean</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Used for Campaign only</label>
            <dataScope>is_campaign_plp</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <checkbox>
                <settings>
                    <valueMap>
                        <map name="false" xsi:type="number">0</map>
                        <map name="true" xsi:type="number">1</map>
                    </valueMap>
                    <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                </settings>
            </checkbox>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

When I'm using `<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Cpy_Cms/js/form/element/plp-campaign</item>`
My checkbox systematically send the value 0 in the php form request.

var_dump($this->getRequest()->getParam('is_campaign_plp')); //0 everytime

If I remove that js file...the data is properly sent.

var_dump($this->getRequest()->getParam('is_campaign_plp')); //0 ou 1 depending on what i checked.

Inside my js...the value seems to be well recovered as the show hide is working fine.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/form/element/checkbox'
], function ($, _, uiRegistry, checkbox) {
    'use strict';

    return checkbox.extend({

        initialize: function() {
            console.log("initialize");
            var self = this;
            self.inputName = 'is_campaign_plp';
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var interval = setInterval(function() {
                    if (jQuery('[name="is_campaign_plp"]').length > 0) {
                        self.onUpdate();
                        clearInterval(interval);
                    }
                }, 200);
            });
            return this._super();
        },

        configureDataScope: function () {
            var recordId,
                value;

            recordId = this.parentName.split('.').slice(-1)[0];
            value = this.prefixElementName + recordId;

            this.dataScope = 'data.' + this.inputCheckBoxName;
            this.inputName = this.dataScopeToHtmlArray(this.inputCheckBoxName);

            this.initialValue = value;

            this.links.value = this.provider + ':' + this.dataScope;
        },

        /**
         * On value change handler.
         *
         * @param {String} value
         */
        onUpdate: function (value) {
            console.log("update");
            if(undefined === value) {
                value = uiRegistry.get('index = is_campaign_plp').value();
            }
            console.log(value);

            var categs = uiRegistry.get('index = categories'),
                customerAccount = uiRegistry.get('index = customer_account'),
                customerAccountUnderNav = uiRegistry.get('index = customer_account_under_nav');

            if(value === '1') {
                categs.hide();
                customerAccount.hide();
                customerAccountUnderNav.hide();
            } else {
                categs.show();
                customerAccount.show();
                customerAccountUnderNav.show();
            }
            console.log(value);
            return this._super();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: When you view the form as rendered by the browser, does the checkbox have the right `name` attribute?

Comment: @jiheison Yes and I can see his value changing correctly both in html and js.